# Getting widget is not defined error when clicking login button in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am having trouble with making a button to open different .ui file but I am keep running into an issue where it says that 'widget' is not defined and then the program crashes.

Could someone give me what I might have done wrong with my gotoLogin?

Below are my code and ui files.

main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

import sqlite3

# loading welcome screen
class welcomeScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(welcomeScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi("welcomeScreen.ui", self)
        self.login.clicked.connect(self.gotoLogin)

    def gotoLogin(self):
        login = loginScreen()
        widget.addWidget(login)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)

class loginScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(loginScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi("login.ui",self)
        self.passwordField.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.login.clicked.connect(self.loginFunction)

    def loginFunction(self):
        user = self.emailField.text()
        password = self.passwordField.text()

        if len(user)==0 or len(password)==0:
            self.loginError.setText("Please input all the fields.")

        else:
            conn = sqlite3.connect("petData.db")
            cur = conn.cursor()
            query = 'SELECT password FROM login_info WHERE username = \''+user+"\'"
            cur.execute(query)
            result_pass = cur.fetchone()[0]
            if (result_pass == password):
                print("Successfully logged in.")
                self.error.setText("")
            else:
                self.loginError.setText("Invalid Username or Password")

# main
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    welcome = welcomeScreen()
    widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    widget.addWidget(welcome)
    widget.setFixedWidth(1200)
    widget.setFixedHeight(800)
    widget.show()
    try:
        app.exec_()
        #sys.exit(app_exec())
    except:
        print("Exiting gracefully")

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main()
```

welcomeScreen.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1200</width>
    <height>800</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="bgWidget" native="true">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1200</width>
     <height>800</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QWidget#bgWidget{
background-color:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.0590406, y1:0.165, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(209, 107, 165, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255))}</string>
   </property>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>510</x>
      <y>190</y>
      <width>191</width>
      <height>71</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">font: 36pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;; color:rgb(255, 255, 255)
</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Cat Care</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>440</x>
      <y>230</y>
      <width>311</width>
      <height>111</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">font: 16pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;; color:rgb(255, 255, 255)</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Sign in or create a new account</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="login">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>440</x>
      <y>340</y>
      <width>301</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">border-radius:20px; 
background-color: rgb(170, 255, 255);
font: 14pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;
</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Log in</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="create">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>440</x>
      <y>420</y>
      <width>301</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">border-radius:20px; 
background-color: rgb(170, 255, 255);
font: 14pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;
</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Create a new account</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

login.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1200</width>
    <height>800</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="bgWidget" native="true">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1200</width>
     <height>800</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QWidget#bgWidget{
background-color:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.0590406, y1:0.165, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(209, 107, 165, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255))}</string>
   </property>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>540</x>
      <y>200</y>
      <width>191</width>
      <height>71</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">font: 36pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;; color:rgb(255, 255, 255)
</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Login</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>450</x>
      <y>230</y>
      <width>311</width>
      <height>111</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">font: 16pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;; color:rgb(255, 255, 255)</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Sign in to your existing account</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="login">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>450</x>
      <y>540</y>
      <width>301</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">border-radius:20px; 
background-color: rgb(170, 255, 255);
font: 14pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;
</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Log in</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>510</x>
      <y>130</y>
      <width>191</width>
      <height>71</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">font: 36pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;; color:rgb(255, 255, 255)
</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Cat Care</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="emailField">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>450</x>
      <y>360</y>
      <width>301</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
font: 12pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="passwordField">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>450</x>
      <y>450</y>
      <width>301</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
font: 12pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>460</x>
      <y>330</y>
      <width>281</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">font: 10pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Username</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>460</x>
      <y>420</y>
      <width>281</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">font: 10pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Password</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="loginError">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>460</x>
      <y>500</y>
      <width>291</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">font: 12pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;; color:red;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\documents\sideProject\pyqt5\CatCare\main.py", line 18, in gotoLogin
    widget.addWidget(login)
NameError: name 'widget' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `widget` is a local variable of `main`. This means that it is only visible within the scope of `main`. To be able to use it within `welcomeScreen` you would have to make it a global variable. That being said, it's rarely a good idea to have a class modify global variables. In your case a better solution would be to remove the functionality of adding widgets to the stacked widget from `welcomeScreen` altogether. Instead, you could subclass `QStackedWidget` and move all the functionality of adding widgets and switching between widgets in there. The subclass could look something like this:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QStackedWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.welcome_screen = welcomeScreen()
        self.login_screen = loginScreen()

        self.addWidget(self.welcome_screen)
        self.addWidget(self.login_screen)

        self.setFixedWidth(1200)
        self.setFixedHeight(800)

        self.welcome_screen.login.clicked.connect(self.goto_login)
        self.goto_welcome()

    def goto_login(self):
        self.setCurrentIndex(self.indexOf(self.login_screen))

    def goto_welcome(self):
        self.setCurrentIndex(self.indexOf(self.welcome_screen))
```

`welcomeScreen` would simply be something like

```
class welcomeScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(welcomeScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi("welcomeScreen.ui", self)
```

and the main function would become

```
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MainWindow()
    widget.show()
    try:
        app.exec_()
        #sys.exit(app_exec())
    except:
        print("Exiting gracefully")
```